# How to format a message in jQuery custom validator method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, credit-card

I am trying to write a custom method as below to validate a credit card number using jQuery validate.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ValidateCreditCard", function(value, element, params) {
    var selectedElement = $('input[name="CardType"]');
    var cardType = selectedElement.filter(':checked').val();
    var cardNumber = $("#CardNumber").val();
    if (cardType == "MasterCard" && !value.startsWith(5)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (cardType == "Visa" && !value.startsWith(4)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a {0} card number"));
```

Based on to card type radio button selection, I would like display the appropriate message.
For example, if user selects Visa credit card, then error message should be please enter a visa card number likewise for Master credit card

Any thoughts on how to pass a card type value to format the message?

Comment: Just an FYI, the `element` keyword represents the element you're validating and `value` represents its value.  So you don't need `$("#CardNumber").val()`... instead, `value` is the same.  In fact, it looks like you're defining a `cardNumber` variable for nothing because you're already correctly using `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

**HTML**

```
<form id="CHECKFORM" name="CHECKFORM">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="CardType" id="radioVisaCard" value="Visa" />
        <label for="MOBILE">Visa</label>
        <input type="radio" name="CardType" id="radioMasterCard" value="MasterCard" />
        <label for="MOBILE">Master</label>
        <input type="text" class="cardNumber" data-rule-validatecreditcard="true" />    
    </div>    
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script>    
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("ValidateCreditCard", function (value, element) {
        var selectedElement = $('input[name="CardType"]');
        var cardType = selectedElement.filter(':checked').val();
        if (cardType == "MasterCard" && !value.startsWith(5)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (cardType == "Visa" && !value.startsWith(4)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, function (element) {
        var selectedElement = $('input[name="CardType"]');
        var cardType = selectedElement.filter(':checked').val();
        var startDigit;
        if (cardType == "MasterCard")
            startDigit = 5;
        else if (cardType == "Visa")
            startDigit = 4;
        return 'The field should be start with ' + startDigit + ' digit.'
    });

    $("#CHECKFORM").validate({
        rules: {
            url: "ValidateCreditCard",
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works great . Thanks for your time .